# Copy-Paste Not Working In DualBoot

Tags: dual-boot, copy

I found a problem that I can't copy files from Ubuntu to Windows in dual boot. I tried to change the permissions using 'chown' but there was an error message: read only filesystem, how can I resolve this problem and return to using it properly?

Comment: If you're trying to copy/share files between Ubuntu and Windows, a much **safer** way is to create a new NTFS partition on your hard disk, call it `Shared` for example, and then paste files into this shared partition when in Ubuntu, and copy them off of the shared partition when you get into Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a 'fast startup' feature that shutdown Windows in a kind of hibernate state. It is not a full shutdown, this can make your Windows drives mounted as read only by Ubuntu.

To make your windows drives writable under Ubuntu, you must perform a **full shutdown of windows** : 
Option 1 : Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while pressing the shutdown button of Windows
Option 2 : In a Windows command line window, type `shutdown /f /p`

You can also disable the 'fast startup' feature from windows power control panel 
[image: disable Windows fast startup feature]